# Use Linq to select distinct on a single column then databind repeater VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

This works:

```
    Dim cmdSelect As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim dtr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim strSelect As String
    strSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT DVIRDate FROM dbo.tblDVIR " _
        & "WHERE (DVIRDate > DATEADD(day, - 30, { fn NOW() }))"
    cmdSelect = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSelect, ConDB)
    ConDB.Open()
    dtr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
    'Bind to Repeater
    Repeater1.DataSource = dtr
    Repeater1.DataBind()
    dtr.Close()
    ConDB.Close()

   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
   <ItemTemplate>  
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DvirDate")%>
   <br />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

But this does not:

```
    Dim db As New DataContext
    Dim sel = From a In db.tblDVIRs _
              Where a.DVIRDate > DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30, Now()) _
              Select a.DVIRDate _
              Distinct

    Repeater1.DataSource = sel
    Repeater1.DataBind()
```

I get an HttpException, "DataBinding: 'System.DateTime' does not contain a property with the name 'DvirDate'."

Interesting enough, when i bind to a gridview with autogenerated columns = true, it works and the column is named "Item"

Am I just not using the right expression in the `databinder.eval` or doing something else wrong? this should be easy in Linq, I've tried everything I can think of in the `databinder.eval()`, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between those two cases. The first one is binding a `DataReader` so the `Eval` method is using it like reader("DvirDate") which works. The second is creating an array of `DateTime` struct. This array has a property named `Item` so auto generating columns bring this column name, but each item is a `DateTime` and doesn't have a property named DvirDate.

You can solve it in two ways:

1. Create a type that contains a property "DvirDate".

   Dim sel = From a In db.tblDVIRs _
                 Where a.DVIRDate > DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30, Now()) _
                 Select New With {.DVIRDate = a.DvirDate} _
                 Distinct
2. Change the databinding expression to:

   `<%# Container.DataItem %>`